# Why were this question and answer so widely upvoted?

Tags: discussion

[What happens to Cessna electric flaps that are moving when power is lost?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/65679/what-happens-to-cessna-electric-flaps-that-are-moving-when-power-is-lost/65682#65682)

I'm certainly not complaining, and I'm glad my answer was appreciated, but I'm a little puzzled. Both question and answer seem pretty middle-of-the-road to me. What made them so compelling?

Answer (score 2):

The post went viral . The site's algorithm ([What are the criteria for questions to be selected for Hot Network Questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60756/392799)) decided to promote the post, so it appears to the sister-sites under Hot Network Questions on the right-hand side.

You can tell from the [timeline](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/65679/timeline) and number of views. >2.5k views is definitely not aviation.se's frequent visitors. You can compare with views of other posts.

Some hot posts can fizzle out (the hotness value keeps updating). This one probably gained traction due to the clear nature of the explanation, and possibly the interesting nature of the question to a wider-audience.