# Why was my question about tyre smoke viewed 2k times and upvoted 5x in just 24 hours?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Yesterday I posted [this question about tyre smoke of big and small airplanes](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/90319/why-dont-small-aircraft-produce-tyre-smoke-when-landing-but-big-aircraft-do). I got answers very fast which is great. Then, I closed the tab and went to do something else.
When I checked my SE inbox this morning, I almost fell from the chair to see that I had got 3 upvotes, 1000+ views and the "question with 1k views" badge in only 12 hours ! In the rest of the day, I got another 1000 views and another two upvotes. Of course I'm happy about this :) - but I would like to know why ? Could it be a bot ?

Comment: See also: [Why were this question and answer so widely upvoted?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3834/14897)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question was featured as a "Hot Network Question" on the right hand sidebar across the Stack Exchange network. This made it easy for lots of people to see your title and find it interesting enough to click on. The featured questions are chosen based on algorithms and it mostly comes down to luck. They call it the "Hot Network Question lottery." Congratulations on winning!

Comment: Oh - I can't see it there, but that is the solution, then. Thank you !

Comment: @Programmer You can see it in your post's [timeline](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/90319/timeline).